# Hacer un map de una respuesta de un Web API REST

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

Estoy tratado de hacer un `map` de una respuesta de un *Web API REST*. Al momento de hacer `.map` sobre el objeto `http.get` el *TypeScript* me devuelve este error:

> La propiedad 'map' no existe en el tipo 'Observable'.ts(2339)"

Aclaro que importé el `map` de la siguiente manera, `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map;`. También probé con `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` y me sigue marcando el mismo error. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Las versiones que tengo son:

- *Angular CLI*: *7.0.7*
- *Node*: *11.1.0*
- *Angular*: *7.0.4*
- *rxjs*: *6.3.3*
- *typescript*: *3.1.6*

Les adjunto el código con el error. Solo me queda marcado con error el `.map`.

```
getinfo(){
    this.http.get(this.url).map((resp:any) => {
      this.info = resp;
      return this.info;
    };   
}
```

Comment: Hola ya logre solucionar el problema les dejo la solución para que tengan de referencia: import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; y el código quedaría asígetinfo(){

    this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map((resp:any) =>{
      this.info = resp;

    }))
  }

Answer (score 1):

Les dejo la solución que encontré

hacemos la siguiente importación en el servicio:

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

y el código quedaría

```
getinfo(){

this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map((resp:any) =>{
  this.info = resp;

}))}
```

hay que ingresar un .pipe y luego el map completen toda la sentencia del map para que se elimine el error por completo.

Answer (score 0):

El operador `map` es un transformador, lo que hace es que toma el valor que le toca en la cadena de operadores en el `pipe` y devuelve un nuevo valor basado en ese, el cuál podría ser el valor de entrada de otro operador o ser el valor final.

Supongamos que obtienes un número 2 en tu *API*:

```
this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
    map(n => { return n * 2}), // 2*2=4
    map(n => { return n * 4})  // 4*4=16
)
```

El valor al final sería 16, porque el valor original se fue transformando a través de los `map`. Por eso mismo, tú lo estarias usando mal, porque lo que te interesa es crear un *efecto secundario* a partir del valor que viene en la respuesta *HTTP*, no transformar esa respuesta misma.

Podrías usar el operador `tap` en su lugar, cuyo objetivo es exactamente lo que deseas hacer: Utilizar el valor de respuesta sin transformarlo.

```
this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
    tap(n => { console.log(n * 2)}), // 2*2=4
    tap(n => { console.log(n * 4)})  // 2*4=8
)
```

Por supuesto `map` te está funcionando, como podría hacerlo `filter` o tantos otros operadores que existen en *rxjs*, pero es mejor usar `tap` ya que para eso fue creado.

Ahora, por otro lado, podrías lograr lo mismo de otras maneras que tendrían mas sentido. Por ejemplo:

- Suscribirte al *Observable* devuelto por `this.http.get()` te daria los mismos resultados... Pero tendrias que manejar el ciclo de vida de la suscripción.
- Tambien podrías usar `this.http.get(this.url).toPromise()` y manejarte como si fuera un *Promise*... Pero sería nadar en redundancia.
- Usar `async pipe`. **Recomiendo firmemente esta opcion**, porque es simple, no tienes que manejar el ciclo de vida del *Observable* y tu código lucirá mejor. [Cómo usar `async pipe`](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe)